# How to retrieve a datetime record, convert to a new timezone and returned the results grouped by the new datetime, without ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, select

I need to create a query that will convert the datetime to a new timezone and group by this field.  Is there a way to do this in rails, without receiving a ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY error?  The following gives me the error, because I am not grouping by a selected field.

`result = eventReading.select(counts, m, b, min(datetime) As datetime).where(dateime: Time.now).group("DATE(SUBTIME(CONVERT_TZ(datetime, 'GMT', 'America/New_York').order("datetime ASC").all`

Comment: every column that is not in the group by needs an aggregation  function

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `subtime` you can group by using

```
.group(
  "date(convert_tz(datetime,'UTC','America/New_York'))"
)
```